# 405 The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'. but I'm using POST

Tags: iis, .net-framework

I hosted a WebAPI application in IIS with no code changes.  When I call a certain url, I get a 405 with an error message in the response body saying GET is not allowed, but I'm calling with POST.

In troubleshooting, I found that calling with other methods gives me a 405, and the method in the error message matches the one I used.  This is expected, but the confusing part is that I'm using POST and the error message says that GET is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from http to https.  I think in the new network, there's some rule about requiring https. I think the reason it was listing a different method is that it was redirecting me to a default site, and the 405 was coming from there.